# What does "if w in [1..5, 8, 11]" mean in pseudo code?

Tags: pseudocode

In some pseudocode, I saw the following:

```
if w in [1..5,8,11]
```

Does it mean that if w is from 1 to 5 or 8 or 11? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's how I'd interpret that. That's not just pseudocode; it's actually valid code in Pascal, exactly as written.

Answer (score 0):

It means "if W is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, or 11".